# change label colors on floating labels

Tags: html, css

i created a  floating label, wich changes the border color and the label element. my question is how to change the label color when input has some content inside?

The color should be pink when the input is focused, but when someone is typing something and click somewhere else, the color should be change back to normal

js

```
$('.form-control').on('focus blur', function (e) {
  $(this).parents('.form-group').toggleClass('focused', (e.type === 'focus' || this.value.length > 0));
})
.trigger('blur');
```

css

```
#floating-label .form-group .form-control {
  border:none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 0;
}

#floating-label .form-group {
  display: flex;
  height: 55px;
}

#floating-label .form-control:focus{
  border-color: #FF4070;
}

#floating-label .control-label {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0.4;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(6px, 22px, 0) scale(1);
  transform-origin: left top;
  transition: 240ms;
}

#floating-label .form-group.focused .control-label {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(0.75);
  color:  #FF4070;
}

#floating-label .form-control {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

#floating-label .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
  transition: 240ms;
}

#floating-label .form-control:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  transition: none;
}

#floating-label .form-group.focused .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #bbb;
}
```

html

```
  <form id="floating-label">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Example label</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Another label</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </form>
```

[bootply](http://www.bootply.com/ET9yKIXcBP)

Comment: This is not happening in my case, it works perfectly. make sure something on your local is not conflicting

Comment: i tested on many devices, and every time if there is content inside the input fields, the labels stays pink and does not change back to default color

Answer (score 2, accepted):

U need to change ur script to this one

```
$('.form-control').on('blur', function (e) {
  var parent = $(this).parents('.form-group');
  parent.removeClass('focused');
  if(this.value.length > 0) {
      parent.addClass('filled');
  }
})
.trigger('blur');

$('.form-control').on('focus', function (e) {
  var parent = $(this).parents('.form-group');
  parent.removeClass('filled');
  parent.addClass('focused');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You just need to add an additional `if` statement to check the length and change the style.

```
$('.form-control').on('focus blur', function (e) {
  $(this).parents('.form-group').toggleClass('focused', (e.type == 'focus' || this.value.length > 0));

  //below lines added
  if(this.value.length > 0) {
    $(this).prev('.control-label').css('color', 'black');
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your javascript to this:

```js
$('.form-control').on('focus blur', function (e) {
        $(this).parents('.form-group').toggleClass('focused');
    })
```

```css
#floating-label .form-group .form-control {
  border:none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  border-radius: 0;
}

#floating-label .form-group {
  display: flex;
  height: 55px;
}

#floating-label .form-control:focus{
  border-color: #FF4070;
}

#floating-label .control-label {
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 400;
  opacity: 0.4;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate3d(6px, 22px, 0) scale(1);
  transform-origin: left top;
  transition: 240ms;
}

#floating-label .form-group.focused .control-label {
  opacity: 1;
  transform: scale(0.75);
  color:  #FF4070;
}

#floating-label .form-control {
  align-self: flex-end;
}

#floating-label .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
  transition: 240ms;
}

#floating-label .form-control:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  transition: none;
}

#floating-label .form-group.focused .form-control::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="floating-label">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Example label</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="control-label">Another label</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control">
    </div>
  </form>
```